# How to change the color of the div once by once? Question about selecting rule in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am new to jquery. I am confused by the selecting rule in jquery. I create 3 questions and want user to click the answer. The div of the color change blue if correct and red if wrong. However, if i just click the correct answer on the first question, all of the color of the div of wrong answer have also changed. What should I do?

Thanks for seeing, highly appreciated!

```js
$(".correct ").click(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', '#b8daff');
  $(".wrong").css('background-color', '#f5c6cb');
});
```

```css
.correct,
.wrong {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #b1dfbb;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>QUESTION</p>
<div class="question">
  <div class="d-flex inline">
    <div class="w-50 correct">A. Correcrt Answer</div>
    <div class="w-50 wrong">B. Wrong answer </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>QUESTION</p>
<div class="question">
  <div class="d-flex inline">
    <div class="w-50 correct">A. Correcrt Answer</div>
    <div class="w-50 wrong">B. Wrong answer </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>QUESTION</p>
<div class="question">
  <div class="d-flex inline">
    <div class="w-50 correct">A. Correcrt Answer</div>
    <div class="w-50 wrong">B. Wrong answer </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Image for demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTLNo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code is selecting *all* `wrong` answers:

```
$(".wrong").css('background-color', '#f5c6cb');
```

**You need to find the wrong answer associated with the question (not just the answer next to the correct one)**. You can do that by using `$(this).parent()` to get the question and then `find(.wrong)` will find it's child that has the "wrong" class.

```
$(this).parent().find(".wrong").css('background-color', '#f5c6cb');
```

**Working snippet (Updated to show it working with different orders and multiple options)**:

```js
$(".correct ").click(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', '#b8daff');
  $(this).parent().find(".wrong").css('background-color', '#f5c6cb');
});
```

```css
.correct,
.wrong {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #b1dfbb;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>QUESTION</p>
<div class="question">
  <div class="d-flex inline">
    <div class="w-50 correct">A. Correcrt Answer</div>
    <div class="w-50 wrong">B. Wrong answer </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>QUESTION</p>
<div class="question">
  <div class="d-flex inline">
    <div class="w-50 wrong">A. Wrong answer </div>
    <div class="w-50 correct">B. Correcrt Answer</div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>QUESTION</p>
<div class="question">
  <div class="d-flex inline">
    <div class="w-50 wrong">A. Wrong answer </div>
    <div class="w-50 wrong">B. Wrong answer </div>
    <div class="w-50 correct">C. Correcrt Answer</div>
    <div class="w-50 wrong">D. Wrong answer </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**  (As Carsten asked in their comment below)

Presumably the correct answer isn't *always* going to be the first answer (that wouldn't be very effective!) - or even the *next* answer if there are more than 2 answers to the question.

The reason I have suggested this approach rather than just using `next()` is because it will find the wrong answer regardless of where it is or how many other answers there are for the question (e.g. it will still work if you have 2 or 3 wrong answers)

Comment: Given the OP's code why use `.parent().find(".wrong")` when `.next()` would result in the same solution?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Because I answered based on what it's trying to do rather than just the MRE code - I assume the correct answer isn't *always* going to be the first one (its kind of a give away).

Answer (score 1):

Do this :

```
$(".correct ").click(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', '#b8daff');
  $(this).next().css('background-color', '#f5c6cb');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
$(".correct").click(() => {
  $(this).css('background-color', '#b8daff');
  $(this).next().css('background-color', '#f5c6cb');
});
```